# Using SignalR to stream data

Tags: c#, signalr

I'm just getting started with SignalR and I'm wondering how to get it work for my task at hand.

Lets say I have a list (in C#) of size 30.
I would like to push out to the client x number of that list at a time.
The client will pass in x and then the server will pass out x by x until end of the list.

I have gotten a code working but its showing weird result. Hope for anyone to help me.

My codes are:

My PersistentConnection class

```
public class MyConnection1 : PersistentConnection
    {
        protected override Task OnConnected(IRequest request, string connectionId)
        {
            return Connection.Broadcast("connection " + connectionId + " connected!");
        }

        protected override Task OnReceived(IRequest request, string connectionId, string data)
        {
            int milisecons = 2000;
            List<string> myList = new List<string>();
            myList.Add("1");
            myList.Add("2");
            myList.Add("3");
            myList.Add("4");
            myList.Add("5");
            myList.Add("6");
            myList.Add("7");
            myList.Add("8");
            myList.Add("9");
            myList.Add("10");
            myList.Add("11");
            myList.Add("12");
            myList.Add("13");
            myList.Add("14");
            myList.Add("15");
            myList.Add("16");
            myList.Add("17");
            myList.Add("18");
            myList.Add("19");
            myList.Add("20");
            myList.Add("21");
            myList.Add("22");
            myList.Add("23");
            myList.Add("24");
            myList.Add("25");
            myList.Add("26");
            myList.Add("27");
            myList.Add("28");
            myList.Add("29");
            myList.Add("30");

            int no = Convert.ToInt32(data);

            var dividedGroupList = myList.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x }).GroupBy(x => x.Index / no).Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList()).ToList();

            dividedGroupList.ForEach(x => { Connection.Send(connectionId, x); Thread.Sleep(milisecons); });

            return null;
        }
        protected override Task OnDisconnected(IRequest request, string connectionId)
        {
            return Connection.Broadcast("connection " + connectionId + " disconnected!");
        }
    }
```

My HTML Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var connection = $.connection('/echo');
            connection.start().done(function () {
                $('#message').append('<li>yay</li>');
            });

            $("#btn").click(function () {
                connection.send($('#msg').val());

                connection.received(function (data) {
                    $('#message').append('<li>' + data + '</li>');
                });
            });
            $("#dcbtn").click(function () {
                connection.stop();
            });
        });
    </script>

    <input type="text" id="msg" />
    <input type="button" id="btn" value=" ME!" />
    <input type="button" id="dcbtn" value=" DC" />

    <ul id="message"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

The output the first time the "ME!" button is pressed (So sorry for not having enough reputation to post image here)

```
•yay
•1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
•11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
•21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
```

The 2nd time the "ME!" button is pressed

```
•yay
•1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
•11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
•21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
•1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10                        <==== repeated here onwards
•1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10                           
•11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
•11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
•21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
•21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
```

The number of repetitions will keep increasing by 1 regardless of whether I click the "DC" button (which invoked the "connection.stop()" method) or not.

Any advice would be plentiful enough

Thanks a lot!

**Edited**
I managed to get this working using Hubs. However, I still would like to know what is actually happening at this low level. What is it that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, PersistentConnection should only be used if you've got a specific scenario that requires it- use Hubs instead.

Second, you shouldn't ever block the thread in a Hub or PersistentConnection object- the object represents a connection operation, so it's transient for the life of the connect event, disconnect event, or method call.

Instead, create an application that then can make a call into a hub- maintain the timer in the application. See the following for how to call into a hub:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub

Comment: Well, I did managed to get it working in hubs.
I was just trying to understand more by using the lower level Persistent Connection. I am very well aware that the thread in Hub or PersistentConnection object is for the life of the connect, disconnect event or method call. However, what if I would like to have more control over when it closes and open? Is it possible?

Comment: I can't think of a way you'd control the connection life cycle using SignalR- you could try programming using WebSockets directly, but then you'd have to code for what happens if WebSockets isn't available (one of the scenarios that SignalR handles for you). What purpose would having control over the connection serve? If you're running a long-running process, it's best under the current architecture to run it outside the hub method, as I described-